# How to set default criteria for all search operations for model?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, criteria

I have a model:

```
class Service extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public static function getMainPageItems()
    {
        return self::model()->findAll(array(
            'condition' => 'on_main = 1',
            'order' => 'pos ASC'
    ));

    public static function getNonMainPageItems()
    {
        return self::model()->findAll(array(
            'condition' => 'on_main = 0',
            'order' => 'pos ASC'
    ));
}
```

I want to set the model's default order to `pos ASC`.

How can I set the model's default order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `CActiveRecord::defaultScope()` method as follows:

```
class Service extends CActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public function defaultScope(){
        return array(
            'order'=>'pos ASC'
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

This will be added for all find methods on the model. Read on [scopes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#scopes-detail) and [defaultScopes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#defaultScope-detail) for more information

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to add a private member to the parent class called $order.

You would need to create getters and setters for it (so that you can change the defalut when you want)

Then simply call `$this->$order` in the 'order' element in each function that requires it.

Comment: Thanks, i know this way. But what about framework posibilities for this moment?

Comment: ah, my mistake (not that familiar with it)